# see below for the detail or details

Tags: articles, plural-forms, singular

When writing an article, I often have to mention *something* but the detail about the *something* is actually described a little bit later. In that case, which of the following is most appropriate? Or how should I decide which one to use?

> (see below for the detail)
>
> (see below for details)
>
> (see below for the details)

Comment: Related question at ELU: [Detail or Details? Read on for more detail/details](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/123672/detail-or-details-read-on-for-more-detail-details)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Details is usually pluralized in such contexts. If there is only one detail, I would probably word it as, "See below for further information."

The article is optional. There's nothing wrong with it, but it is usually omitted for the sake of brevity. You can have a look at [this Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=see+below+for+details%2C+see+below+for+the+details&year_start=1940&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3) to see which is the more idiomatic wording.

Comment: Awesome! The link is very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I'd prefer having the definite article as *the details* are right below the subheading/line. Nevertheless, as J.R. comments/answers, it's not mandatory and is less common as well.

It depends whether you are talking about [detail or details.](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/123672/detail-or-details-read-on-for-more-detail-details)

But my suggestion is while *writing*, we don't instruct the reader to *see/look*. Though it's correct, I don't prefer it. Maybe, this is a better choice...

> Here are the detail/s *OR* 
>  Below are the detail/s

Comment: There's no need for the article. Read my answer for details.

Comment: @J.R. I know that but when I'm talking about the details, right there, below the heading, does not it require the article? *Read my answer for details* I fully agree. But here, I'm talking about the text, right below the heading. Quite similar to *[Here are the details you required](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3675/is-details-singular)*

Comment: Required? Absolutely not. See the Ngram in my answer. Including a "the" in this stock phrase is actually rather rare.

Comment: @J.R. edited. I always used the article. Thanks for sharing :)

Comment: I think the article would be more likely to be included in a statement like "Here the details you requested," but there's something about "See below" that makes the article unnecessary. I would probably say "See below for details," but, if I rearranged the words, I might say "See the details below."