# "I login" vs "I am logged in" vs "I had been logged in"

Tags: verbs

I am writing an email with a snippet of what I see as the first page after I login successfully with my credentials. When introducing this image, which of the following is appropriate?

> I see below at website after **I login** successfully.
>   I see below at website after **I am logged in** successfully.
>   I see below at website after **I had been logged in** successfully.

Comment: Can you give us some context of what you're trying to say? Right now, I don't think that any of the three are perfect.

Comment: I am writing an email with a snippet of what I see as the first page after I login successfully with my credentials

Comment: Great! I've edited that into your question. In the future, it can help us out a lot if you will give us that sort of background info when you ask the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As to your main question, either "I log in" or "I am logged in" will work just fine, though I'll point out that, in this case, you want to use "log in" rather than "login". Yes, "login" is a word but it's not the word you want here.

You could actually also say "after I have/have been logged in successfully", too, if you want to use had/have, though "have been" passes the attribution of the action to some other entity, so it looks like something else is logging you in. So, some of your options include:

> I see ... after I log in successfully.
>   I see ... after I am logged in successfully.
>   I see ... after I have logged in successfully.
>   I see ... after I have been logged in successfully. (with hesitations)

Your third option won't work because "had" doesn't agree with your present tense "see". You could make "see" into the past tense "saw" and use this form, though it'd be more common to use the past tense "logged in" instead.

> I saw ... after I logged in successfully.
>   I saw ... after I was logged in successfully. (with hesitation)
>   I saw ... after I have logged in successfully.
>   I saw ... after I have been logged in successfully.

For some reason, in the past tense, the version I don't like as much changes, as noted above.

In interest of completeness, I would recommend a slight adjustment to the rest of your sentence:

> I see **the** below [result] **on the** website after I log in/am logged in successfully.

Mostly, you're missing a couple of articles and we use "on" when describing web page content.

We do say "[see below](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/49208/see-below-for-the-detail-or-details)" quite often but usually when it's a command - "See below for more information."

Other rephrasings that work and are more explicit about what you're saying include:

> The image below is what I see **on the** website after I log in/am logged in successfully.
>   I took the below screenshot on the website after logging in.

Answer (score 0):

I would say to use this:

> I see below at website after I login successfully.

I login: Login is a present tense verb, so "I login" is saying "I login (right now)".

I am logged in: Saying that you have logged in **already** and you are stating that.

I had been logged in: Past tense. Saying that you **were** logged in, but the sentence is presuming you are no longer logged in.